# add background image with SCSS in Ruby on Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I'm taking a course in Web-development and have just started with Ruby on Rails.
The thing i'm trying to figure out now is how i can set a background image with scss.

My image is in app/assets/images.

The things i have tried is:

```
img-url(asset_path 'logo.png')
image-url('<%= asset_path 'logo.png' %>')
url('/asset/logo.png');
```

and a few more. But the image does not show.
I have read on stackOverflow on many people asking this question, but all the solutions in there did not work for me.

Any suggestion on how i can achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `image-path`? `image-path('logo')`?

Comment: Just tried it, it did unfortunately not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with CSS files and images you have two options `url` and `path`:

- `image-url("logo.png") # url(/assets/logo.png)`
- `image-path("logo.png") # "/assets/logo.png"`

If you want to work with images, font, video, audio, JavaScript and/or stylesheet files then you can use the generic form

- `asset-url("logo.png") # url(/assets/logo.png)`
- `asset-path("logo.png") # "/assets/logo.png"`

See the [`ActionView::Helpers::AssetUrlHelper`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-asset_path) for further information.

Comment: asset-url("logo.png");

That one did work tho :) Thanks alot for the help.